# Regex replace to a string without space at the end and beginning

Tags: regex, postgresql, regexp-replace

I want to remove the following characters {}, _ from a string and make it initcap.

```
{OTHER_QUESTIONS,MISSING_DOCUMENT}
```

**Desired outcome:**

```
Other Questions, Missing Document
```

I tried the following but it adds space to the first and last characters, so how can I achieve the desired outcome above?

```
regexp_replace(INITCAP('{OTHER_QUESTIONS,MISSING_DOCUMENT}'), '[{}_]', ' ', 'g'),
```

Comment: `TRIM(BOTH FROM regexp_replace(INITCAP('{OTHER_QUESTIONS,MISSING_DOCUMENT}'), '[{}_]', ' ', 'g'))` this will remove leading and trailing space as well.

Comment: Does it also mean you want to add a space after `,` if missing?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sql
SELECT INITCAP(
  TRIM(
    REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE('{OTHER_QUESTIONS,MISSING_DOCUMENT}', ',(\S)', ', \1', 'g'), '[{}_]+', ' ', 'g')
  )
)
```

See [an SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6baaa/11).

The `,(\S)` regex will match a comma and capture into Group 1 any non-whitespace char after it, and replace will `, \1`, that is, a comma, space and the Group 1 value. Then, `[{}_]+` regex will match all occurrences of one or more `{`, `}` and `_` chars and the regexp_replace will replace them with a space, and `trim` will remove the leading/trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

just drop the space in Regex,' '-->'', replace:

```
regexp_replace(INITCAP('{OTHER_QUESTIONS,MISSING_DOCUMENT}'), '[{}_]', ' ', 'g')
```

to

```
regexp_replace(INITCAP('{OTHER_QUESTIONS,MISSING_DOCUMENT}'), '[{}_]', '', 'g')
```